# d3js get corner coordinates of rect

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js

I am trying to draw lines between two rectangles. I want the line to go from the mid of the first rect to the mid of the second rect. For this I need to find the coordinates of the rect. Currently the coordinates for the line are hard coded but this is not a good approach. Please help, thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
  const svgContainer = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1200)
      .attr('height', 8000);

    const A1 = svgContainer.append('rect')
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', 10)
      .attr('width', 550)
      .attr('height', 850)
   
    const A2 = svgContainer.append('rect')
      .attr('x', 680)
      .attr('y', 10)
      .attr('width', 550)
      .attr('height', 850)

 const lineA1ToA2 = svgContainer.append("line")
                       .attr("x1", 10)
                       .attr("y1", 270)
                       .attr("x2", 680)
                       .attr("y2", 270)
                       .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                       .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no "center coordinates" in javascript and svg. so you would need to calculate these coordinates by yourself. In your case the best option would be to put params into variables and calculate all the coordinates based on them

```
const x1 = 10, y1 = 10, width1 = 550; height1 = 850;
const x2 = 680, y2 = 10, width2 = 550, height2 = 850;
    const A1 = svgContainer.append('rect')
      .attr('x', x1)
      .attr('y', y1)
      .attr('width', width1)
      .attr('height', height1)
   
    const A2 = svgContainer.append('rect')
      .attr('x', x2)
      .attr('y', y2)
      .attr('width', width2)
      .attr('height', height2)

 const lineA1ToA2 = svgContainer.append("line")
                       .attr("x1", x1 + width1 / 2)
                       .attr("y1", y1 + height1 / 2)
                       .attr("x2", x2 + width2 / 2)
                       .attr("y2", y2 + height2 / 2)
                       .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                       .attr("stroke", "black");
```

maybe some variables are redundant, as  you repeat some sizes. just added them for more general case